# A symplectic basis extending a given isotropic subspace

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F$, and let $\omega \colon V \times V \to F$ be a symplectic form.
That is, $\omega$ is bilinear, alternating, and non-degenerate.

Let $\{a_1, \dots, a_s\} \subseteq V$ be a linearly independent set such that $\omega(a_i,a_j) = 0$ for all $1 \leq i,j \leq s$.

I am looking for a reference showing that there exist $a_{s+1}, \dots, a_t, \dots b_1, \dots, b_t \in V$ such that $\{a_1,b_1, \dots, a_t,b_t\}$ is a symplectic basis of V. 
This means that $$\omega(a_i,b_j) = \delta_{ij}, \ \omega(a_i,a_j) = \omega(b_i,b_j) = 0.$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure you know the proof yourself, right? If not afraid of a german ref, it is in my linear algebra book, second part.

Comment: @StefanWaldmann Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at any introductory text on symplectic geometry.  For example, you could look at Lecture 5 of my [Lectures on Lie groups and symplectic geometry](https://services.math.duke.edu/~bryant/ParkCityLectures.pdf), but, really, this material could be found pretty much anywhere.

Anyway, you could just prove it yourself:  If $s<t$ (where $\dim V = 2t$) then the $s$ equations
$$
\omega(a_1,x) = \cdots = \omega(a_s,x) = 0\tag 1
$$
are $s$ linearly independent equations for $x\in V$ and hence there will exist $2t-s$ independent solutions.  Since $2t-s > s$, there must be an $a_{s+1}$ linearly independent from $a_1,\ldots, a_s$ that satisfies (1).  This can be repeated until you get up to a sequence $a_1,\ldots, a_t$ that is linearly independent and satisfies $\omega(a_i,a_j)=0$ for $1\le i,j,\le t$.

Now, a simple argument using linear independence and nondegeneracy shows that you can find $c^i$ for $1\le i\le t$ satsifying $\omega(a_j,c^i) = \delta^i_j$, and that the $2t$ vectors $a_i$ and $c^i$ are linearly independent.

Now, set $b^i = c^i + s^{ij}a_j$ and solve for the $s^{ij}$ so as to satisfy $\omega(b^i,b^j) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks Robert! This is also the argument that I had in mind, but I just wanted a reference for this to cite in a paper.